# How to simulate Trial mode on Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, trial

I've been developing and testing WP apps for more than year, including paid apps with trial versions, Silverlight and XNA too. When using **Guide.SimulateTrialMode** and **Guide.IsTrial** in WP7 SDK, it was perfectly working in emulator and on real device as well. Now when I use this same approach in WP8 SDK for WP8 apps, when I set SimulateTrialMode to true, then Guide.IsTrial still returns false. I've even tried LicenseInformation.IsTrial() and it is returning false as well.

The question is, am I doing something wrong, or it is no longer possible to simulate the trial mode using Guide.SimulateTrialMode in WP8 apps? Note when I use this for WP7.1 apps with WP8 SDK, it works just fine, so I guess it's only bug in WP8 apps.

I've checked these guides, but there is no hint that SimulateTrialMode is broken on WP8:
[Creating trial apps for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Guide.SimulateTrialMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.simulatetrialmode.aspx)
[App platform compatibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

tl;dr **SimulateTrialMode is not working in WP8 apps**, any other way, how to simulate Trial mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is, instead of calling directly `Guide.IsTrialMode`, I wrap it in a property:

```cs
public static bool IsTrial
{
    get
    {
        return Guide.IsTrialMode;
    }
}
```

The point is that you can now easily change the property to return true or false during your test. You can even use preprocessor directives and a specific build configuration to switch to trial mode:

```cs
public static bool IsTrial
{
    get
    {
#if TRIAL
        return true;
#else
        return Guide.IsTrialMode;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended with as well. Too bad the original solution does not work.